# Opening specific file for writing on memory

Tags: verilog

I wrote this code for initialize my memory. When I run it behaviorally, it says that it can not open file.

```
module DataMemory (Address, WriteData, Clk, MemWrite, MemRead, ReadData); 

    input [4:0] Address;   // Input Address 
    input [7:0] WriteData; // Data that needs to be written into the address 
    input Clk;
    input MemWrite;         // Control signal for memory write 
    input MemRead;          // Control signal for memory read 

    output reg[7:0] ReadData; // Contents of memory location at Address
    reg [7:0] Memory[0:31];    // size needs to be adjusted based on the size of the test_data.txt

    always @(posedge Clk) begin      //Memory write
        if (MemWrite==1)
            Memory[Address] = WriteData;
    end

    always @(Address or MemRead) begin
        if (MemRead == 1)
            ReadData <= Memory[Address];    //Memory read
    else
        ReadData <= 8'h00;
    end 

    initial begin
        $readmemh("test_data.txt", Memory,0,31);
        // Notes: 
        // 1-make sure to adjust the "Memory" size based on your test input
        // 2-watch out for wild characters at the end of the last entry in your test file

    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error, and does the test_data.txt file exist? which folder is it in?

Comment: This is the actual error:WARNING: File test_data.txt referenced on C:/Users/Elnaz-laptop/Desktop/Project/Memory/Memory.srcs/sources_1/imports/insertion_sort/memory.v at line 53 cannot be opened for reading. Please ensure that this file is available in the current working directory.

Comment: The test_data is existed, I add this file as a source file when I created the project. When I check this file in the project folder, It is existed there, I do not know why the simulator can not open the file.

Comment: are you just using a single folder for holding all files and simulation. I am guessing it is compiling and running from a different folder. have you tried putting the full path into readmemh ?

Comment: You mean I write the file direction in readmemh function?? I do not know how to do this!!!

Comment: Was thinking more of `$readmemh("C:/Users/Elnaz-laptop/Desktop/Project/test_data.txt", Memory,0,31);`

Comment: Thank you, I apply this format and it works.

Comment: Good to see this highly stupid problem still exists.  Shame they cant fix the script to be relative to the project path or better still just have the app change the working path to the project path.

Answer (score 0):

```
module DataMemory(Address, WriteData, Clk, MemWrite, MemRead, ReadData); 

input [4:0] Address;   // Input Address 
input [7:0] WriteData; // Data that needs to be written into the address 
input Clk;
input MemWrite;         // Control signal for memory write 
input MemRead;          // Control signal for memory read 

output reg[7:0] ReadData; // Contents of memory location at Address

reg [7:0] Memory[0:31];    // size needs to be adjusted based on the size of the test_data.txt

always @(posedge Clk) begin      //Memory write
    if (MemWrite==1)
        Memory[Address] = WriteData;
end

always @(Address or MemRead) begin
    if (MemRead == 1)
        ReadData <= Memory[Address];    //Memory read
else
    ReadData <= 8'h00;
end 

initial begin
    $readmemh("C:/Users/Elnaz-laptop/Desktop/test_data.txt", Memory,0,31);
    // Notes: 
    // 1-make sure to adjust the "Memory" size based on your test input
    // 2-watch out for wild characters at the end of the last entry in your test file

end

endmodule
```